# Download a link based on Content-Type JavaScript Casperjs

Tags: javascript, download, casperjs, content-type

I'm a beginner programmer in CasperJS and I'm writing a crawler that collects each link on the site, I'm hoping to download based on content type.

```
var links = this.evaluate(function() {
    var links = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(__utils__.findAll('a'), function(e) {
        links.push(e.getAttribute('href'));
    });
    return links;
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) {
    //get content-type of link 
    //download based on context type ie. images or text
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the `"resource.requested"` event to look for the content types that you want and `abort()` all the others ([example with `"page.resource.requested"`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-requested)). You can answer your own question when you solve it.

Comment: When I add the function page.resource.requested  - I received the error        ' (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. %d listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit. 11'

Answer (score 0):

```
casper.on("resource.received", function(response){
   "use strict";
    resourcesRec.push(response);
    var file = response.url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    casper.download(response.url,file);
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the question. This will help future searchers learn from what you have discovered.

Comment: I wanted to download urls based off content type. I later then realize I needed to download everything so I provided the code above. To download based on specific URLs, just wrap the download in an if statement if(response.contentType.indexOf('text') > -1) { //download}